# Change Custom Dialog 'header' to AlertDialog 'header'

Tags: android, layout, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have made a custom Dialog, and I want the title to have a background like the AlertDialog.

Better said:

The place where it says "Custom Dialog"

[image]

Needs to have a 'header' like this:

[image]

I don't want to just add the image left to the text, but really implement the complete UI style shown.

Is this possible?

Here's the code I used for my custom dialog: [Adding Image to Custom AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302439/adding-image-to-custom-alertdialog)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Galip this is the code that worked for me

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);

dialog.setTitle("Pick A Colour");
```

and in my dialoglayout I had root element RadioGroup

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So why not using the classical `AlertDialog.Builder` ?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( activity );
builder.setTitle( title );
builder.setView( /* Your custom view here */ );

// optional
builder.setPositiveButton( R.string.button_ok, listener );
builder.setNegativeButton( R.string.button_cancel, listener );

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

You will then have the system dialog look and feel.

Comment: Already tried that, I just don't know how to build the XML-view that looks EXACTLY like the normal listview-like content *only* with another textview aligned to the right side.